# Call a cell by using a value in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a simple cell (Eg: =a1) in Excel. However this "a1" is available in another cell, let's say in cell 'e1'.

In another way, what I mean is e1 cell has the value "a1" in it and for that reason alone I want to call a1. Finally will in turn populate the value that is actually in a1.

I need to do this is because the cell no. that needs to be populated is retrieved from a formula in e1. That is how the cell a1 comes into the picture.

Comment: `=INDIRECT(E1)` will return the value in A1 if E1 contains the text 'A1'

Answer (score 1):

Using the function: `=Indirect([cell])` will give you the value in the [cell]. For example, if cell Z1 has the function `=Indirect(E1)`, and E1 has the value A1, will give you the value of A1 in Z1. Then if E1 changes to, say, A2, then cell Z1 will contain the value from A2.